# Django clone model object with class based createview

Tags: django, django-views, clone

I want to prepare a new object but wait for user input to create it:

I've added `get_form` to this view:

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(MyCreateManView, self).get_form(form_class)
        if self.kwargs['ref']:
            new_item = get_object_or_404(models.MyModel, pk = self.kwargs['ref'])
            new_item.pk = None 
            new_item.note = "Copia di " + new_item.note 
            form =  MyForm(instance = new_item)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

In the method, I read the GET parameter 'ref' and precompile the form fields with that data.

But when I submit the data, the `form_valid` method is not executed and the new object is not created.

Comment: `if form.is_valid(): form = form.save(); context = {
        "form": form,
    } ; return render(request, "app/template.html", context)`

Comment: Is it a class based view or a normal view? If it is not a class based view then `super(MyCreateManView, self).form_valid(form)` doesn't make much sense. Have you got this code from somewhere else and copied in bits and pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do,

```
form  =  MyForm(instance = new_item)
```

you are not binding the form to any data. This means that the form will never be valid.

I would try overriding `get_form_kwargs` instead.

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    if self.kwargs['ref']:
        new_item = get_object_or_404(models.MyModel, pk = self.kwargs['ref'])
        ...
        kwargs['instance'] = new_item
    return kwargs
```

Answer (score 2):

The marked answer cannot be correct since I tested it and it will overwrite your existing object!

Use below instead (tested on Django 2.17 )

```py
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()

        old_item = get_object_or_404(Tutorial, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        new_item = deepcopy(old_item)
        new_item.id = None
        kwargs['instance'] = deepcopy(new_item)

        return kwargs
```